# How can I test Akka become/unbecome transitions?

Tags: akka

Is there a recommended way of testing that an actor has properly changed its behavior using become? One of the reasons I prefer using FSM is because I can easily verify that an Actor has changed its behavior.  I don't know how I am supposed to do this when using become/unbecome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I suppose it would be possible to roll out a custom pub/sub thingy, which would notify subscribers about state transitions, I wouldn't bother if I were you. What you want to test is the **new behavior** not the fact that the transition was caused by an implementation detail like become/unbecome or FSM for that matter. Although it is quite easy to do this with FSM, I give you that ;)

Comment: I agree here.  Let's say that one message would trigger the behavior change and then a subsequent message would be handled in a different way.  Then this is what you should be testing.  That after receiving the first message, the second message produces different results.