# neat way to test become unbecome swtichover in scala

Tags: scala, unit-testing, tdd, akka, actor

I am trying to test state switch over of receive method.
Found [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20833038/how-can-i-test-akka-become-unbecome-transitions) post, but that also not clearly give a solution.
Please find below simplified code snippet :-

```
package become_unbecome_basics

import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorSystem}
import akka.testkit.{ImplicitSender, TestActorRef, TestKit}
import become_unbecome_basics.BasicBecomeUnbecomeActor.{SWITCH_TO_MASTER, SWITCH_TO_STANDBY}
import com.typesafe.scalalogging.LazyLogging
import org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike
import org.scalatest.Matchers._

class BecomUnbecomeSwitchoverTest extends TestKit(ActorSystem("testSystem")) with ImplicitSender with FlatSpecLike{

  "initially receive" should "points to master" in {
    val aRef = TestActorRef[BasicBecomeUnbecomeActor]
    val actor = aRef.underlyingActor

    //not sure, weather we have something like this to assert
    //actor.receive should be(actor.master)
  }
}

object BasicBecomeUnbecomeActor{
  case object SWITCH_TO_MASTER
  case object SWITCH_TO_STANDBY
}

class BasicBecomeUnbecomeActor extends Actor with LazyLogging{
  override def receive: Receive = master

  def master: Receive = {
    case SWITCH_TO_STANDBY =>
      context.become(standBy)

    case msg => logger.debug(s"master : $msg received")
  }

  def standBy: Receive = {
    case SWITCH_TO_MASTER =>
      context.unbecome()

    case msg => logger.debug(s"standBy : $msg received")
  }
}
```

Comment: Consider using the [Akka Finite State Machine](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/fsm.html) instead of trying to `unbecome`.

Answer (score 1):

The StackOverflow post you mentioned contains two suggested ways to test your actor.

1. Emit the state changes to some other actor.
2. Don't test state change, but the actor's behaviour.

In the first example, you would have some way of sending information out of your actor on every state change. In Akka, sending state change information as actor messages is natural way to implement this.

```
import akka.actor._
import akka.testkit._

class ExampleActor(notify: ActorRef) extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  import ExampleActor.{Master, StandBy}

  def receive: Receive = master

  def master: Receive = {
    case StandBy =>
      notify ! StandBy
      context.become(standby)

    case msg =>
      log.debug("received msg in master: {}", msg)
  }

  def standby: Receive = {
    case Master =>
      notify ! Master
      context.become(master)

    case msg =>
      log.debug("received msg in standby: {}", msg)
  }
}

object ExampleActor {
  def props(notify: ActorRef): Props = Props(new ExampleActor(notify))

  case object Master
  case object StandBy
}

class ExampleActorTest extends TestKit(ActorSystem("testSystem")) with FlatSpecLike {

  "ExampleActor" should "move to stand by state" in {
    val probe = TestProbe()
    val actor = system.actorOf(ExampleActor.props(probe.ref))

    actor ! ExampleActor.StandBy

    probe.expectMsg(ExampleActor.StandBy)
  }
}
```

(I haven't run the code yet so apologies for any errors in the code)

In the code above, the `ExampleActor` is a stateful actor which notifies the given actor reference of any state changes. Note that this doesn't allow inspecting the current state, but instead a log of state transitions. Also, it is possible to introduce a bug in the state notification code because the notification code is manually added to the actor instead of the actor doing it automatically.

I changed the testing style to [asynchronous testing style](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/testing.html#Asynchronous_Integration_Testing_with_TestKit) to get more realistic tests.

The state change notifications allows you to get information about what specific state the actor transitions to, but it doesn't tell you if it works the way it should. Instead of testing what state changes the actor goes through, how about testing what the actor itself does.

```
class Accumulator extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  import Accumulator._

  def receive: Receive = accumulatorReceive(0)

  def accumulatorReceive(x: Int): Receive = {
    case Add(i) => next(x + i)
    case Remove(i) => next(x - i)
    case Multiply(i) => next(x * i)
    case Divide(i) => next(x / i)
    case Get => sender() ! x
  }

  def next(x: Int) = context.become(accumulatorReceive(x))
}

object Accumulator {
  def props: Props = Props(new Accumulator)

  case class Add(i: Int)
  case class Remove(i: Int)
  case class Multiply(i: Int)
  case class Divide(i: Int)
  case object Get
}

class AccumulatorTest extends TestKit(ActorSystem("testSystem")) with FlatSpecLike {

  import Accumulator._

  "Accumulator" should "accumulate" in {
    val probe = TestProbe()
    val actor = system.actorOf(Accumulator.props)

    actor ! Add(3)
    actor ! Remove(1)
    actor ! Multiply(4)
    actor ! Divide(2)

    probe.send(actor, Get)
    probe.expectMsg(5)
  }
}
```

In this example, `Accumulator` does state changes, but it doesn't notify when its state has changed. Instead, it has a specific get command for inspecting interesting parts about its state. In the test, we send multiple messages that cause state changes in the accumulator actor. Finally, we inspect the result of these messages by querying the accumulator.